# flutter multiple state management

Tags: flutter, flutter-state

I have a sized box like so

```
    child: SizedBox(
        width: 50.0,
        height: 50.0,
        child: DecoratedBox(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue
          ),
        )
    ),
```

i would like to change the color of the box decoration depending on the value of a piece of state called _status, _status can have four values 1,2,3,4, and depending on the value of status I would like to change the color of the box decoration like so
1 - blue
2 - red
3- amber
4 - green

The ternary statement that is normally used does not help as it is only good with a limited number of values of the state is there a way that I can implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define helper function to calculate Color value

```
child: SizedBox(
     width: 50.0,
     height: 50.0,
     child: DecoratedBox(
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
           color: _getBoxColor(),
       ),
     )
 ),
 
//somewhere below build method
Color _getBoxColor() {
 switch (_status) {
   case 1:
     return Colors.blue;
   case 2:
     return Colors.red;
   ...
 }
```